# Pandas dataframe KeyError while working with CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, keyerror

I have this code as shown:

```
for filename in glob.glob('/Users/jacob/Desktop/MERS/new/NOT COAL/gensets/statistics_per_lgu/per_lgu_files/*.csv'):


    # For fuel consumption
    count = df_csv['Fuel Type_Jundy'].count()
    aa = df_csv['Fuel Type_Jundy']
    d = aa.value_counts()

    ADO = d['ADO']
    Bunker = d['Bunker']
    LSFO = d['LSFO']
    IFO = d['IFO']
    LPG = d['LPG']


    fuel_type = pd.DataFrame({'count': count, 'ADO':ADO, 'Bunker':Bunker, 'LSFO':LSFO, 'IFO':IFO, 'LPG':LPG},
                             index=['fuel_type'])
```

A KeyError occurs since, not all csv files contain 'ADO', 'Bunker', LSFO, etc. at the same time.

What can I do so that I could get this dataframe

```
  fuel_type = pd.DataFrame({'count': count, 'ADO':ADO, 'Bunker':Bunker, 'LSFO':LSFO, 'IFO':IFO, 'LPG':LPG},
                         index=['fuel_type'])
```

such that whatever is in *.csv (be it LSFO, ADO, Bunker, etc.) has its count in the dataframe.

Thanks! :D

Comment: Please can you show a short example from some of the input files? Ideally one with and one without some of the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be a cleaner/shorter way to do this, but you could 'try' to assign the value counts to a variable individually, and if it doesn't exist, then save it as NaN

```
import numpy as np
try:
    ADO = d['ADO']
except:
    ADO = np.nan
try:
    Bunker = d['Bunker']
except:
    Bunker = np.nan
```

etc...

that way the code will run even if there isn't an entry in the csv file, and when you make the df the missing values will just be NaN and the values that are there will be correctly stored